# How to search for patterns to find the positions of prime numbers

Tags: pattern-matching, prime-numbers

I have a summation which yields a prime number at each location there is a 2, and I do not know how to search for the 2's.

```
N[Sum[1/(10^(n*4) - 1), {n, 1, 100}], 10^2*4]
```

> ```
> 0.0001000200020003000200040002000400030004000200060002000400040005000200060002000600040004000200080003000400040006000200080002000600040004000400090002000400040008000200080002000600060004000200100003000600040006000200080004000800040004000200120002000400060007000400080002000600040008000200120002000400060006000400080002001000050004000200120004000400040008000200120004000600040004000400120002000600060009000
> ```

In the above example, I want to find the positions of the form/pattern `0002` in the output. It should yield all the prime locations under 100.  I have tried using `Position[list,form]` by putting the expression in for the list and putting the `Out` in for the list, without success. Do I have to make a list first out of the decimal output, and if so, how do I make a list with chunks of 4 digits, and then search it? Below is what I've tried.

```
Position[N[Sum[1/(10^(n*4) - 1), {n, 1, 10}], 10^2*4], 2]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

```
Position[%%, 0002]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

Comment: The output is not list. it is an atomic number. so what do you mean by position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slighlty different [`RealDigits`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealDigits.html) approach:

```
N[Sum[1/(10^(n*4) - 1), {n, 100}], 10^2*4];

Partition[RealDigits[%][[1]], 4, 4, -1] ~Position~ {0 .., 2} // Flatten
```

> ```
> {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41,
>  43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97}
> ```

Comment: @Karsten Thanks for pointing out my mistake.  By the way I already voted for your answer; I guess I should have read it more carefully.

Comment: This method is slower but easier on the monitor display, it's a tough choice of which one is better for dealing with large numbers. Thanx for your contribution.

Comment: I've been using this method exclusively now since trying to do larger numbers, and it's the best. thanks once again. I have a new formula that can give the primes in a specified range. At higher ranges, there are less primes. What happens when there are no results to display? Does the progran know how to terminate? Do you know a bit of code I could include for when there are no primes, that would return a default like zero ?

Comment: @user24719 If `Position` finds no matches it returns `{}`.  You could therefore check to see if the result is (`SameQ`) `{}` replace it with whatever you wish.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with (SameQ). I would have to see it put into practice for me to understand it. The coding aspects of everything I'm trying to do is just so way over-my-head. I understand the Math but not the Mathmatica language. I haven't learned all the magical words to chant, And the documentation only gets me so far. That's why I greatly appreciate the help you've given me. You've helped me take a concept off the drawing board and actually give it some wheels, some realization. Thank you so much.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a bit of code to add onto the answer you gave me above, the

Comment: @user24719 I meant something like this: `Partition[RealDigits[%][[1]], 4, 4, -1] ~Position~ {0 .., 2} // Flatten // (If[# === {}, 0, #] &)`

Comment: @user24719 By the way I am sorry to see that the questions we migrated to [Math.SE] have been ignored.  I still think that is the right place for them but I hoped for more.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. Or I'll just look for {}. It is helpful to have something to look for so that I know the programming has run its course. Eventually I am thinking of having this project of mine being a distributed computing project like GIMPS, but even better, because what I am doing allows for the proving of primes at the square root of time it takes to do trial division. But I am having issues. I asked the following question at the following link provided and someone voted to close it on me. Said they don't understand the math behind it. I thinking of doing a youtube to explain all.

Comment: Here is that link,                                                                                                          http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/206201?noredirect=1

Comment: N[Sum[2/10^((n*(Floor[9/n] + 1) - 9)*4), {n, 1, Floor[Sqrt[ 9]]}] + Sum[ 2/(10^((n*(Floor[9/n] + 1) - 9)*4)* (10^(n*4) - 1)), {n, 1, Floor[Sqrt[ 9]]}] + Sum[2/(10^((o^2 - o - 9)* 4)*(10^(o*4) - 1)), {o, Floor[Sqrt[9]] + 1, 20}], ((20 + 1)^2 - 9)* 4]; AbsoluteTiming[Flatten[ Position[Partition[ RealDigits[%][[1]], 4, 4, -1], {(0) .., 2}]]] + 9

Answer (score 7):

One approach would be to first convert the output of

```
N[Sum[1/(10^(n*4) - 1), {n, 1, 100}], 10^2*4]
```

to a `String` dropping the leading `0.`

```
str = StringDrop[ToString@%, 2]
```

Than one can use [`StringPosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringPosition.html?q=StringPosition)

```
Last /@ StringPosition[str, "0002"]/4
```

> ```
> {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79,    
>  83, 89, 97}
> ```

---

An other approach would be to use the `RealDigits` of

```
N[Sum[1/(10^(n*4) - 1), {n, 1, 100}], 10^2*4]
```

In this case we have to add the first `000`

```
{0, 0, 0}~Join~First@RealDigits[%]
```

Then this list can be partitioned into sublist of length 4 and converted to digits

```
FromDigits /@ %~Partition~4
```

Now the position of the `2`s can be found with

```
Position[%, 2] // Flatten
```

> ```
> {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 
>  83, 89, 97}
> ```

Or

```
Flatten@Position[
  Tr /@ (RotateLeft @@ RealDigits[%]) ~Partition~ 4,
  2]
```

> ```
> {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 
>  83, 89, 97}
> ```

Comment: Okay, so I put it all together into one input, like this

Comment: N[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 
    1\), \(100\)]\(1/\((\((10^\((\((n)\)*4)\))\) - 1)\)\)\), (10^2)*4]
str = StringDrop[ToString@%, 2]
Last /@ StringPosition[str, "0002"]/4

Comment: and I still got three outputs on screen. The problem I have with this is that this toy problem is simple, and the real problems I want to solve are much bigger, so much bigger that one would never want the output displayed on screen. I would prefer to "export to file", so my follow up question is how to do this, export and import outputs? I've tried by myself, like this

Comment: In[78]:= N[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 
     1\), \(100\)]\(1/\((\((10^\((\((n)\)*4)\))\) - 
      1)\)\)\), (10^2)*4] >> "ddneg100"
str = StringDrop[ToString@"ddneg100", 2] >> "ddneg100string"
Last /@ StringPosition[str, "0002"]/4

Out[80]= {}

Comment: and I get nothing for in brackets, just empty brackets. Please help.

Comment: Oh, and I've developed a newer form of summation after I discovered there was a symettry in all the ones and zeros. It uses only the square root number of terms of the previous version. It is

Comment: N[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 
    1\), \(10\)]\(2/\((\((10^\((\((\((n^2)\) - 
           n)\)*4)\))\) \((\((10^\((n*4)\))\) - 1)\))\)\)\), (10^2)*4]
str = StringDrop[ToString@%, 2]
Last /@ StringPosition[str, "0002"]/4

Comment: the only difference being that the n^2 placeholders have a two instead of a one. Hence, one is now included in the list. If you learn to ignore this one exception, the results are virtually the same.

Comment: The purist would use N[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n = 
    1\), \(10\)]\(\((\((10^\((n*4)\))\) + 
     1)\)/\((\((10^\((\((\((n^2)\))\)*4)\))\) \((\((10^\((n*4)\))\) - 
       1)\))\)\)\), (10^2)*4]str = StringDrop[ToString@%, 2]
Last /@ StringPosition[str, "0002"]/4

Comment: but really, now I'm splitting hairs in comparison.

Comment: And another thing that would be nice to know, is how or where to use //AbsoluteTiming without screwing things up with the string.

Comment: This answer has been working for me until I get into large numbers. It's quicker but harder for the display to keep up. And I am getting false positives with this method.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = N[Sum[1/(10^(n*4) - 1), {n, 1, 100}], 10^2*4];
Quotient[3 + SequencePosition[RealDigits[a][[1]], {0, 0, 0, 2}][[All, 2]], 4]
```

> {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 
>   67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97}

Answer (score 0):

```
N[Sum[2/(10^(Mod[-(10 - n^2), n]*4)*
      (10^(n*4) - 1)), 
 {n, 1, Sqrt[10000]}], (10000 - 10)*4]
str = StringDrop[ToString[%], 2]
(1/4)*Last /@ StringPosition[str, 
     "0002"] + 10
```

100 seems to be the practical limit when it comes to computer runtime. I asked my 32GB RAM computer to do 1000 and it just keeps running forever. It's still impressive that I can get all the primes under 100^2 in the blink of an eye, but not near as impressive as I need it to be to look for primes in the range that will win the EFF Award for largest provable prime. I'm going to try to work on a method that goes in the positive direction instead of the negative decimal direction.

Comment: Please learn how to format your posts. You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  The edit window  help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

I just invented this last week.

Copy the following into Mathematica, select all, right-click on Convert To, choose StandardForm.

```
N[Sum[2/10^((n*(Floor[c/n] + 1) - c)*s), {n, 1, Floor[Sqrt[ c]]}] + Sum[2/(10^((n*(Floor[c/n] + 1) - c)*s)* (10^(ns) - 1)), {n, 1, Floor[Sqrt[ c]]}] + Sum[2/(10^((o^2 - o - c) s)*(10^(o*s) - 1)), {o, Floor[Sqrt[c]] + 1, max}], ((max + 1)^2 - c)*s]; AbsoluteTiming[Flatten[ Position[Partition[ RealDigits[%][[1]], s, s, -1], {(0) .., 2}]]] + c

-end

c=crossover s=spacing
```

The crossover is the number which you want to surpass. The spacing is difficult to determine, so I'll say that, in general, if you use a number which is equal to the number of digits of the `max^2`, you should be safe. For all primes up to `100^2 = 10000`, that is five digits, so use a 5 for the spacing. Follow this rule and you should be safe.

For those who are wondering, the code is based on a bigger structure of numbers formed by the Sieve of Eratosthenes.